How do I fix this epub file? (Remove "profile" that prevents opening in Cantook)
I am using the Cantook ebook reader (formerly Aldiko) on a Samsung Galaxy Tab S8. Most of the epub files I have will open just fine; however, I’m getting an error with one file that I can’t get around:
OpenError.ProfilesNotSupported: Cannot open a publication with profiles: [Profile(uri=https://readium.org/webpub-manifest/profiles/epub)]

When I open this with Calibre’s reader/editor, I can’t find any reference to that URL.  The Calibre library manager recognizes it as epub, and the reader has no trouble opening it.
There is no DRM on the file; I can do as I please to it - but I have no idea what I need to do to make this file readable by Cantook (beyond "remove the profile" somehow), or how to do it.
Advice?

In sheer desperation, I tried using Calibre to convert it from ePub to Mobi, and then converted the Mobi back to ePub - which seems to have worked. I will probably not mark this answer as accepted, in hopes that someone can come up with a better answer and/or an explanation of just what was going on with the original ePub.

It's probably using some kind of shortened call to the manifest. There are numerous ways to do that. Evidently completely unnecessary that it happens since epub-->mobi-->epub fixed it. But to find what it is specifically  I would have to take a look at the problem epub -- if so I would then expand my own epub knowledge and yours, could be fun. If it's something that needs remain private I understand as well, just thought I'd offer.
